# How to display a list of all `man` pages available on the system?

Tags: linux, debian, man

I learn Linux partly by reading `man` documentation.

I often find relevant `man` pages using `apropos` or `man <command>`.

However, I've come across many "hidden" gems, like `man credentials` and `man unix` that I didn't knew existed before I saw other `man` pages refer to them.

Is there a way to list all `man` pages available on the system, so that I can get a complete overview of what's available?

I tried looking into `man --all --regex <regex>`, but it seems that `man` opens the matching `man` pages instead of listing them.

Comment: Try `apropos -r .* | less`. Is that what you are looking for? If you want to limit to man levels, you can use `apropos -s <level> -r .*` (for instance `apropos -s 3 -r .*`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
man -k .
```

- `-k` Equivalent to apropos.

Comment: Thank you. Here `.` matches any char?

Comment: Isn't `-k` (`apropos`) implied by default?

Comment: Yes, `.` matched any char

Comment: What do you mean by "builtins"? On my system `man .` and `man -k .` produces identical output (Debian 9)